# How to use multiselect in streamlit to persist records

Tags: python, exception, streamlit

I have an excel database and two fields one screen. One is filters which is multiselect and has options like color and type. And the other is model which shows the records from database depending upon the filters selected, again this is multiselect.
I want the user should have the flexibility to reuse the filters for model. i.e.
If i select Color: Blue and Type: Sedan the model field should show all the cars from DB which satisfy this condition and one selecting one among them the user can again chain and reuse the filter to add new model in the list for eg color: Red and Type: compact so now the model shows unique value from db which satisfy this criteria. The model should persist even after changing filter and selecting something else. I tried using session but it gives StreamlitAPIException: Every Multiselect default value must exist in options. Is this limitation of multiselect?